# how to make the dropdown appear in default structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, dropdown

hello friends i have a drop down menu ,which appears and disappears on alternate clicks.

But when I click the  list  third time ,the entire list appears (multiple drops appears unclosed). How can I make the list appear back in default structure?

Here is my code. Please help.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <style>
    .dropdown-submenu {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
      top: 0;
      left: 100%;
      margin-top: -1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Multi-Level Dropdowns</h2>
    <p>In this example, we have created a .dropdown-submenu class for multi-level dropdowns (see style section above).</p>
    <p>Note that we have added jQuery to open the multi-level dropdown on click (see script section below).</p>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
<span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e) {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hide the sub-dropdowns when the main dropdown is closing.

You can do this by listening to the [`hide.bs.dropdown`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#dropdowns-events) event.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <style>
    .dropdown-submenu {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
      top: 0;
      left: 100%;
      margin-top: -1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Multi-Level Dropdowns</h2>
    <p>In this example, we have created a .dropdown-submenu class for multi-level dropdowns (see style section above).</p>
    <p>Note that we have added jQuery to open the multi-level dropdown on click (see script section below).</p>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
<span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e) {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
    $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
      $('.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu').hide();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```